# MapReduce for 5 gb files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, large-files

I have a 5gb file. I am running a simple map reduce job of wordcount. the block size is of 128 MB. it is a 1 node cluster . After reading 1.2 million reports. it again starts reading from the start of the same file. Sudo code is below .

```
Configuration objconf = new Configuration()
Path objInputPath = new Path("/home/abc/Desktop/Debug.csv")
Path objoutPath = new Path("/home/abc/Desktop/Outpath.csv")
Job objJob = new Job(objconf, "WordCount")
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(objJob, objInputPath)
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(objJob, objoutPath)
objJob.setJarByClass(WordCount.class)
objJob.setMapperClass(WCMapper.class)
objJob.setJobName("WordCount")
objJob.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class)
objJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class)
int j = objJob.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1

Mapper.java
private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1)
private Text word = new Text()
String line = value.toString()
```

Comment: How do you know that it starts reading from the beginning of the same file?

Comment: If you don't want sudo (sic.) answers please provide real code. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have kept line no in one of the column. lets say it prints 1,2,3 .....1200000 , and after 1200000 it again starts printing 1,2,3,4 ....